# jQuery attribute selector not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm setting up tracking in Google analytics for when someone clicks on a directions link, where the href would contains "maps.google.com...", so here's what I'm using:

```
        // track directions
        jQuery("a[href*='maps.google.com']").click(function(event) {
        console.log('directions link clicked');
        if (typeof gtag !== 'undefined') {
              gtag('event', 'Click', {
                'event_category': 'Contact',
                'event_label': 'Directions',
                'event_callback': function() {
                    console.log("directions tracking sent successfully");
                }

             });
        } // end if variable defined
```

Unfortunately, neither of those console.logs() are triggered.

The following works, however:

```
jQuery("a[href^='mailto']").click(function(event) {

});
```

Is this maybe because my directions link selector contains "."s ?

Comment: Can you add an example of this links?

Comment: Sure, examples would be <a href="mailto:johndoe@example.com">Email Link that works</a>

And <a href="maps.google.com/test">Link for selector I can't get working</a>

Comment: it's working here https://jsfiddle.net/zkp589nd/

Comment: maybe there is another code causing the problem?

Comment: Hm.. Maybe because I have the links open in a new tab, and I'm not preventing the default action?

Comment: add event.preventDefualt() in your click function and then redirect to the url

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1):

So for me it wasn't working because the element was created by a script (Google maps plugin for WordPress).

Here is my working solution:

```
// track directions
        jQuery('body').on("click",  "a[href*='maps.google.com']", function(event) {
        if (typeof gtag !== 'undefined') {
              gtag('event', 'Click', {
                'event_category': 'Contact',
                'event_label': 'Directions',
                'event_callback': function() {
                    console.log("directions tracking sent successfully");
                }

             });
        } // end if variable defined

        }); // end click function
```